# How to window set zoom use Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

In html + SVG,

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #svgWrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 2614px;
    height: 1991px;
  }

  #svg {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 2614px;
    height: 1991px;
  }
```

SVG images are very large (subway map)
Body has a SVG, this operation should be in the mobile.

When you click on an element of the SVG, so I want to create and zoom-in the elements in the center.

The following code've made elements to be positioned in the center.

windo.innerWidth() does not come out properly, do you use the zoom in SVG.

How can you ever change the zoom level of the window itself?

```
setCenterWithStationId: function (station_id){
  station = Snap.select(".station#"+station_id);
  bound = station.getBBox()                          
  var half_width = window.innerWidth/2
  var half_height = window.innerHeight/2
  window.scrollTo(bound.x - half_width, bound.y - half_height);
  }
```

Comment: You use google translator?

Comment: I'm sorry. Translated.

Comment: you can zoom with library -- https://code.google.com/p/svgpan/